# index.py form page processed by guestbook.py with responses? 

Tags: google-app-engine

I need form on index.py, and Datastore query responses ("comment" here) processed by guestbook.py, so form responses display to visitor AFTER form submit, hence 2 pages. I am editing Google's Guestbook to do this as simply as possible before integrating with my app. Datastore is working, but responses are not displaying back to visitor, POST 302.

```
application: guestbook
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /
  script: index.app
- url: .* 
  script: guestbook.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.1"
```

index.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import cgi
import webapp2

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write("""<html>
<body>
          <form action="/sign" method="post">
            <div><textarea name="content" rows="3" cols="60"></textarea></div>
            <div><input type="submit" value="Sign Guestbook"></div>
          </form>
         </body>
         </html>""")

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
  ('/', MainPage),
], debug=True)
```

guestbook.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#
import cgi
import datetime
import webapp2

from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.api import users

class Greeting(db.Model):
  content = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
  date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)


class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    content = self.request.get("content")
    self.response.out.write('<html><body>')
    greetings = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * "
                            "FROM Greeting "
                            "ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1")

    for greeting in greetings:
        self.response.out.write('<blockquote>%s</blockquote>' %
                              cgi.escape(greeting.content))

        self.response.out.write('</body></html>')


class Guestbook(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def post(self):
    content = self.request.get("content")
    greeting = Greeting(content = content)
    greeting.put()
    self.redirect('/')


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
  ('/', MainPage),
  ('/sign', Guestbook)
], debug=True)
```

Comment: Sorry, I left 3 weeks ago. :)

Comment: @NickJohnson left your employer 3 weeks ago? I thought it was the 8th. If I'm wrong, you should update your profile http://stackoverflow.com/users/12030/nick-johnson

Answer (score 2):

The `action` is a URL, not a  module. The only URL you have defined is `/`, which routes to `home.app`. Presumably your form is served by that module.

**Edit** You have completely misunderstood how URLs work in GAE, and in fact in most web frameworks. Neither `index.html` nor `home.py` are URLs for GAE: they are, respectively, an HTML template and a Python file that GAE can use to construct a response to a web request. Your `app.yaml` maps URLs to Python functions. In your case, it maps the URL `/` to the Python function `home.app`, which lives in `home.py`.

At no point would you ever use `home.py` in a URL. As I stated above, the `action` has to be one of the URLs you have defined either in `app.yaml` or, if you are using some framework like webapp that supports routing inside the Python module, one of the sub-URLs defined there.

Of course, you also have the problem that you have mapped `/` to the static `index.html` file, which seems to be completely wrong. I doubt very much you can map the same URL to two handlers in GAE, although I've never tried, but anyway that file is probably a template rather than a file you want to serve as-is. Remove that mapping.

Comment: Aside from pettiness, why -1 on my post? It's well written and thorough. Are you able to suggest a productive solution? Just guessing what you're alluding to: url: /index.html or index.html, or url: /home.py or home.py fails to bring up the page at all.

Comment: OK, I follow about mapping the url. But I DO need to serve index.html as is, and have the form processed by home.py, you know, like cgi-bin/apache2 or php/mysql works. Very basic stuff. Also, I did follow your previous advice to use Jinja2, but arrived at the same problem. So I went back to no template. Using Jinja2 (mostly) separated my html and python, but did not solve my problem.

Comment: @pavl Mapping / to index.html will work fine - but you have to map other paths to other things, too, as per Daniel's advice.

Comment: @Nick Where might one learn how to map other paths to other things, as applies to my code above?

Comment: @pavl From any of the getting started guides or tutorials.

Comment: Wrong, other than the tutorials showing how to put index.html in app.yaml, they fail to show how a form on index.html interacts with Datastore on another Python page. Education is key here, yes?